# ASP.NET MVC3 TryValidateModel validates entire model collection, not just single instance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action that takes a list of models.  I'd like to validate each one individually vs. the entire model collection at once.  I'm trying to use TryValidateModel, but it appears that if any one of my models is invalid, all of them are invalid.  My form displays 5 SurveyResponseModels (a class with two Required strings and two ints).  If I fill out all five models completely, I get validCount = 5 below.  However, if any of the five models are incomplete (thus failing validation), I get a validCount of 0.  Is the expected behavior of TryValidateModel?  If so, any ideas on how I can validate these one at a time?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IList<SurveyResponseModel> respondents)
    {
        int validCount = 0;

        foreach (SurveyResponseModel respondent in respondents)
        {
            if (TryValidateModel(respondent))
            {
                validCount++;
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", validCount.ToString() + " respondents passed validation");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the code, it appears to me that `TryValidateModel` will validate all models of the type given by the object provided, not just that particular object itself.  Moreover, it returns the current value of the `ModelState.IsValid` property so that once there is an invalid model, all invocations of `TryValidateModel` will return false.  If you want to do something like this, I think that you'll need to get and run the validators for each model instance yourself on that particular model instance.

I also think that the model validators have already been run by the time you are invoking them manually.  You can check this (for an invalid model) by looking at the value of `ModelState.IsValid` before your loop.  If it's false, then it means that the validators were run by the model binder, which is what I think happens.

You can find the source code for MVC at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/.

Comment: he´s got a good point. The modelstate is a singular instance, which will save the values for each interaction. As one goes wrong, all of them will fail, due the logic you chose. Perhaps you should try to evaluate each state separately. You can use the IValidatableObject to achieve the behaviour you want

Answer (score 4):

`TryValidateModel()` adds to the list of validation errors. Use `ModelState.Clear()` to remove previous errors.  Validation occurs as part of the model binding process, automatically, unless the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute is used.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581918/1238406 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behaviour in another post.

To continue tvanfosson's suggestion, I suggest you put a breakpoint before your foreach, and check the ModelState to see if the errors are already there. They probably are: the DefaultModelBinder has put them. Then I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. Errors are correctly passed, in some way that identifies each Respondent (I don't think it's the case). In this case a simple linq expression can get you the distinct count of problematic respondents.
2. Errors are mixed, for example if 2 respondents have an invalid Name, you have only one error for Name, or you cannot distinguish which respondent is concerned. In this case you need to create custom validation logic. You can create an object like RespondentListViewModel and create a RespondentListViewModelBinder. You can see the source code above to see how the DefautlModelBinder validates lists and adds model errors.

Yes, it's this part of ASP.NET MVC where the binding logic doesn't do what we want it to do...

Answer (score 1):

the source code:

```
    protected internal bool TryValidateModel(object model, string prefix) {
        if (model == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
        }

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());

        foreach (ModelValidationResult validationResult in ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(metadata, ControllerContext).Validate(null)) {
            ModelState.AddModelError(DefaultModelBinder.CreateSubPropertyName(prefix, validationResult.MemberName), validationResult.Message);
        }

        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }
```

It will always return false, in case one is wrong.