# .NET Core ModelState Validation after setting properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, modelstate

I've got a Web API controller in .NET Core.  I'm posting data to save a new `comment` model, and I have the `AuthorID` property that has a `[Required]` data annotation on the model.

I'm setting the `AuthorID` in the controller before saving.  However, ModelState is always coming back stating that AuthorID field is required.

How do I keep my validations on the model in place and validate correctly in this scenario?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromBody] Comment comment)
{
    comment.AuthorID = Utilities.GetUserId(this.User);
    comment.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        ....
```

Comment: Create a separate type for the incoming data that doesn't include the id https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Answer (score 2):

-You can use TryValidateModel() but first you need to clear the model state and then revalidate the model again
[ASP.NET MVC TryValidateModel() Issues when Model is Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574524/asp-net-mvc-tryvalidatemodel-issues-when-model-is-modified)

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromBody] Comment comment)
    {

        comment.AuthorID = Utilities.GetUserId(this.User);
        comment.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        ModelState.Clear();

        if (!TryValidateModel(comment)) // the same as !ModelState.IsValid
        {
            //Failure 
        }
        //Success 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ModelState validation using

```
ModelState.Remove("AuthorID")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it and keep the validation?  In this example AuthorID could be null, in which case I would like validation to fail.  I could always write this separately, but ideally I'd like ModelState to validate with AuthorID, just after I've set it.

Comment: Is your AuthorID Nullable in Model?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel and pass it to your Controller Post

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromBody] CommentModel comment) 
{}
```

And about other logic that you need AuthorID, Create another ViewModel for that,
Why you decide to depend only on one model for everything !!.