# What is the difference between TryValidateModel and Model.IsValid, which is better to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I use ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and want to pass a `jsonString` object to the contoller,
which I decode into a `Model` object. How can I validate that object?

```
public JsonResult UpdateCategory(string jsonCategory)
    {  
        var categoryWitSubcategories =
              System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<CategoriesEntryViewModel>(jsonCategory);

        // If model is invalid
        if (!TryValidateModel(categoryWitSubcategories))
           // This works...

        }
```

I can't use `UpdateCategory(CategoriesEntryViewModel model)` because I have a byte[] property, and this way it will be `null`.

Comment: Look into [tryvalidatemodel-validates-entire-model-collection-not-just-single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798238/asp-net-mvc3-tryvalidatemodel-validates-entire-model-collection-not-just-single)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference SO

Looking at the code, it appears to me that `TryValidateModel` will validate all models of the type given by the object provided, not just that particular object itself. Moreover, it returns the current value of the `ModelState.IsValid` property so that once there is an invalid model, all invocations of `TryValidateModel` will return false. If you want to do something like this, I think that you'll need to get and run the validators for each model instance yourself on that particular model instance.

I also think that the model validators have already been run by the time you are invoking them manually. You can check this (for an invalid model) by looking at the value of `ModelState.IsValid` before your loop. If it's false, then it means that the validators were run by the model binder, which is what I think happens.